# how to call second job after 60 days of first job is done?

Tags: jenkins

Here I want to execute multiple jobs with a specific gap of days and the second job must be executed after the first job is done.

Counter starts when the first job is done.

Comment: Please post your code or what you have tried so far.

Comment: It's a Jenkins. So, there is no code over here.
There are only configurations to manage it.